# DTCoreText Load Remote CSS

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, dtcoretext

I'm using DTCoreText to convert a HTML file which I download from a server to NSAttributedString and display it in a DTAttributedTextView. The HTML file uses `<link>` tag to include several CSS file, which is also on the same server. However, when I execute the program, texts and images are displayed, but I see the following output in the Xcode console:

```
Mar  3 10:34:18  App[2102] <Warning>: CSS link referencing a non-local target, ignored
Mar  3 10:34:22  App[2102] <Warning>: CSS link referencing a non-local target, ignored
Mar  3 10:34:25  App[2102] <Warning>: CSS link referencing a non-local target, ignored
```

I see these message as informing me that the CSS files linked are not being respected. My question is, how do I make these CSS files respected by DTCoreText? I am certain about the correctness of the HTML code.

My code converting HTML below:

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(htmlData: data, options: [
            DTUseiOS6Attributes: true,
            DTDefaultFontFamily: UIFont.custom(size: 15).familyName,
            DTDefaultFontSize: 15,
            DTDefaultTextAlignment: CTTextAlignment.justified.rawValue,
            DTDefaultTextColor: UIColor.black
            ], documentAttributes: nil)!

textView.attributedString = attributedString
```

whereas `UIFont.custom(size:)` return a valid font and textView is a DTAttributedTextView.

Comment: Did you get solution to this problem? @Edward

Comment: @Rakesh Singh I did a work around: I download the css file along with the html, then specify the css file as the `DTDefaultStyleSheet` in the option array when parsing attributed string.

Comment: Ok I fixed by using UIwebview instead of DTcoretextvire. @Edward. Thanks